# Extract an element from a list and use it to sort the entire list

Tags: haskell

Can u help me with this code .i want to extract the tutor which is the last element in the
 each tuple and use it to sort the entire list.

```
import Data.List

type CourseData = [(String,String,String,String,String)]
l :: CourseData

--list contains name of student, year, programme and personal tutor
l = [("fondi","201202378","2012","Bsc280"," tautology"),
     ("fondi","201202378","2012","Bsc280"," tautology"),
     ("Sylvee","200801245","2008","Bsc209","puma"),
     ("dijeje","201307845","2013","Bsc205","tautology"),
     ("heron","201002567","2010","Bsc280","setlhako"),
     ("slow","201198746","2011","Bsc205"," mampu"),
     ("Sylvee","201198746","2008","bsc209"," puma"),
     ("Sylvee","201198746","2008","bsc209"," puma")]




sortByTutor :: CourseData ->String -> [String]
sortByTutor list  =sort[tutor|(name,id,year,prog,tutor)<-list ]
```

when i use the above method ,it only returns the sorted list of tutors .what can i change so that it returns the whole list sorted according to  the tutor name?

Answer (score 1):

You can try `sortBy` from `Data.List`:

```
sortBy (\(_,_,_,_,t1) (_,_,_,_,t) -> compare t1 t) l
```

Comment: Also note that the names have space in start in your sample data.

Comment: u really saved me  @Ankur

Answer (score 1):

What Ankur said, use `sortBy`. Here is a slightly different way of writing this sort:

```
import Data.List (sortBy)
import Data.Function (on)

sortByTutor xs = sortBy (compare `on` \(_,_,_,_,t) -> t) xs
```

This is useful if you have accessor functions that extract the fields from the tuples, e.g. for tutor:

```
tutor (_,_,_,_,t) = t
```

Then you can simply reuse them:

```
sortByTutor xs = sortBy (compare `on` tutor) xs
```

which is very readable.

Comment: There's even `Data.Ord.comparing` which is equivalent to ``(compare `on`)``.